# Retrieve a nested model of an element of a list in a model

Tags: java, wicket-1.5

I'm stuck with a problem with the wicket models and lists.
Let's say I have a bean like this :

```
public class A{
    private B title;
    private ArrayList<C> childs;
    ...get/set...;
}
```

I create a model from it `new Model<A>(a)` and I want to retrieve nested models of it's attribute. For `B`, it's simple : `new PropertyModel(a,"title")`.

But how can I retrieve a nested model for each child C ? (A model of type `IModel<C>`)

Thanks.

Comment: There's no direct way with PropertyModels. You'd need to create a wrapper that produces a List of IModel<C>s based on your list.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I not a wicket expert and I don't see how to create it and keep the models nested.

Comment: Could you explain, what exactly you mean by "nested", what you want to archive with a nested model and where you's want to use it? There are different solutions for different use cases and I don't know which'd suit your needs.

Comment: My goal is to use theses models in forms (with CompoundPropertyModel) and be sure that on submit the objects in the list are updated.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a Wrapper that delegates most of the work to you actual bean but wrapps the returnvalues in IModels.

This might look similar to this:

```
public class ModelWrapper implements IModel<A> {

    private A data;

    public ModelWrapper(A data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public IModel<B> getTitle() {
        return new Model(data.getTitle());
    }

    public List<IModel<C>> getChilds() {
        return new List<IModel<C>>() {

            @Override
            public int size() {
                return data.getChilds().size();
            }


            @Override
            public IModel<C> get(int index) {
                return new IModel<C>(data.getChilds().get(index));
            }

            ...

        };
    }
}
```